# Could not find SDK folder

Tags: android, eclipse

Every time I open eclipse, I get the following popup.

[image: Could not find SDK folder popup]

At one time I had the Android SDK installed but trashed it. Now I can't figure out how to eliminate this error popup.

Comment: Sounds like you should "open preferences" or uninstall the Eclipse plugin. Or you could just create an empty directory in that location.

Comment: Install Android Studio. If you get error like this is AS, it manages it much better.

Comment: I don't want the Android support any more, that's why I trashed the folder. I uninstalled the Android plugin but the Android preferences remains in the eclipse preferences looking for this folder. And it won't let me blank out the address.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the sdk again.

Download the SDK from here - http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html. Use the link under 'Use and existing IDE' so you don't have to download eclipse again.

Once you have installed the SDK, set the SDK path in eclipse under Preferences - Android heading.

Comment: I don't want the SDK any more, that's why I trashed the folder. But I can't seem to get eclipse to give up on Android preferences.

Comment: Your question was not very clear about that. You may have to completely clear your eclipse settings. But I've never had that issue so I can't be of much help.